# Firebug console suddenly not showing http messages

Tags: javascript, firebug

I have no idea what changed, but now the only way I can see any network (like AJAX) activity from javascript is to go to the network tab.  Just minutes before it would show up in the console like any other sort of debug message.

Anybody have any idea what happened?  I've poked around in the documentation and the different options but nothing is getting the network messages back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [options menu of Firebug's *Console* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel#Options_Menu), there is an option for toggling the AJAX request display called *Show XMLHttpRequests*. You might have pressed this one, and now it filters out the network logs.

See the following image:
[image: FireBug Console Interface]

Comment: You are very welcome :)
@Sebastian Zartner, thanks for the edit